# How to solve this Maple issue?

Tags: maple

Every command I input in Maple it also attach `Typesetting:-mparsed(...)`,like this:

`solve(x^2-2*x+1 = 0, x)`

->`Typesetting:-mparsed(solve(x^2-2 x+1=0,x),solve(x^2-2 x+1=0,x); "_noterminate")`
etc.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFWYI.png)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please put your code into your question instead of using pictures.

Comment: @ScottEvans Have edited

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the latest point-release update. For example, for Maple 2018, the latest is 2018.2.1 available [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/downloads/m2018_2_1update.aspx).

The problem is related to 2D Output, and in particular to "typesetting" of that. It may help for you to change from the default typesetting level of `extended` to the (previous version's default) of `standard`.

You can set that via the menus as a persistent preference, or you can set that programmatically for the current session.

Using the menubar, choose **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Display** and then toggle the **Output display** combo-box from **Extended** to **Standard**.  Then close the preferences dialogue by clicking the button **Apply Globally**. Then close the Maple GUI, and relaunch.

To set it programmatically for the current session, you can issue the command,

```
interface(typesetting=standard):
```

And then try your examples once again.

Are you using an internationalized version of Maple, with a particular locale?

Or, perhaps you are using the Japanese version? In that case make sure you get the right point-release download, as there is one specifically for the Japanese version.

If you really want the typesetting=extended mode, and the latest point-release still has the problem, you could contact Maplesoft's customer support.

Comment: I did not use Japanese version, I am using Chinese version.

Comment: After made the change and I tried to evaluate a function. It returned a mathematical notation instead of an answer.

Comment: It is weird that when I use text mode instead of math, it works. However, I like the math symbol/notation more.